# Airflow occasionally cannot find the local python module

Tags: python, airflow

I import my own python modules via
`pip install -e path`
The webserver warns with `No module named` and cannot import the dag directly.

However, after refreshing, it some import the dag success while sometimes fail.
If I execute it, the tasks are working without error.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of Airflow you are working on?

Comment: On which infrastructure are you running Airflow ?

Comment: The airflow version is 2.2.2 in a docker and I install the python packages directly using pip3 to the same python kernel

Answer (score 0):

what you must do is put all your modules in a folder and then change the environment variable with the value of your modules eg.

```
  - name: PYTHONPATH
    value: "/opt/airflow/modules/"
```

**Remember that for your package folder you must include an `__init__.py` file**

Comment: Where should I put this parameters on? What's the difference from I install the packages directly?

Comment: ahh.. i see. you are not using kuberenetes then. 
Why we do this is because often we dont create packages as such and want to use them like simple python modules and hence provide path to them. In your case you dont need it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out. Because I am using Jupyter Notebook, it creates `.ipynb_checkpoints` for me.
After I remove the folder, all dags work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you installed the module in a different python executable than the one used by airflow. To check the location, run:

`airflow info`

In the result, under the **System info** section, you'll find **python_location**. Copy its value and run:

`<python_location> -m pip install <module>`